# Search multiple spoolfiles in AS400

Tags: logging, search, ibm-midrange

Search multiple spoolfiles in AS400

How do i search multiple spoolfiles at the same time in IBM AS400 for certain messages or errors?

Im no expert but i just would like to have a function that search all spoolfiles from a certain time o or jobs at the same time.

Comment: Which kind of error or message do you want to find ? Searching all spoolfiles may not be the best option.

Comment: Hi!
We are calling external program from AS400 that sends back error messages, instead of going through the logs/spoolfile manually i want to do a search to go through all of them with one search.

Answer (score 3):

With Release `7.2` or Later and `SYSTOOLS` installed you can try the  following
Query.
It uses the `QSYS2.OUTPUT_QUEUE_ENTRIES` view and the `SYSTOOLS.SPOOLED_FILE_DATA` table function to  list all Joblogs with Content in column `SPOOLED_DATA`.

```sql
SELECT JOB_NAME, OUTPUT_QUEUE_NAME, FILE_NUMBER, SPOOLED_DATA
FROM QSYS2.OUTPUT_QUEUE_ENTRIES OQE
CROSS JOIN TABLE(SYSTOOLS.SPOOLED_FILE_DATA(JOB_NAME => OQE.JOB_NAME, SPOOLED_FILE_NAME => OQE.SPOOLED_FILE_NAME, SPOOLED_FILE_NUMBER => OQE.FILE_NUMBER))
WHERE SPOOLED_FILE_NAME = 'QPJOBLOG';
```

Resources:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=services-output-queue-entries-view
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=services-spooled-file-data-table-function

Answer (score 2):

Remember that IBM's SPOOLED_FILE_DATA table function is simply a wrapper for a CPYSPLF followed by a SELECT statement. You can extract the SQL source for it using various available methods to confirm this. When doing many SPOOLED files, such as linking to the OUTQ Entries list, you create many temp/work files. So you want to be sure that's what you need to do.
IBM's Omni Search (or is it Omni Find?) can search SPOOLED files using SQL, but I have no experience with that. There is a pretty efficient READSPLF (Read SPOOLED File data) SQL Table function in the SQL Tools library, but that requires a small license fee. It does not use a work/temp file but instead reads/scans the SPOOLED file content directly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).